# Apache NiFi REST Api using java

Tags: java, rest, apache-nifi

I'm still learning programming Apache NiFi using java and I wonder if anyone could explain to me how to instantiate a NiFi platform using NiFi REST APIs & java? Any solution to create processor using Apache NiFi REST API and java.

**UPDATES**
So I was trying this out :

```
 import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;




public class HttpClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/5f577c63-0170-1000-deb5-b53c37656ad4/template-instance");
         CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            client.close();

            }
        }
```

But always :
[image: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]

Comment: [Can I use Java API's in Apache NiFi](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Can-I-use-Java-API-s-in-Apache-NiFi/td-p/153070):If you are talking about API exposed by NiFi, NiFi exposes a REST API: 

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

If you want to develop your own processor in Java, this is easy and you may find interesting the following:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html

Comment: @y_ug actually I did not understand how to process the java code ?! because I'm newly developer in JAVA and now I'm in an internship period so :( I have no idea how to make a java code that invokes Apache NiFi REST APIs

Comment: Then I'suggest to study examples. Google knows about at least some of them: https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+nifi+custom+processor+example

Comment: Look for any examples how to call any rest API from java. Ask your question with code example and exact endpoint that you want to call.

Comment: @y_ug so here is my code :                                                                                           

   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/5f577c63-0170-1000-deb5-b53c37656ad4/template-instance");
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
   System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
  
         }
     } but it always showing me : 400 BadRequest

Comment: Put you code to the question, not to comment, please.

Comment: @y_ug Ok, look at it now

Comment: you have to send with post request the json payload. you could check body by using dev-tools (f12) in your browser and import the template. or read it in documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 2):

NiFi provides a swagger definition for working with the REST API, so you can generate your own client for your preferred language using Swagger Codegen.
[Here are instructions on how to do this for Python](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devnotes.html#generate-swagger-client) as a part of my Python client for NiFi, it should be a good beginner step to modify them for Java rather than working with the raw JSON/REST calls.

Here's the main part of the process:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp && \
echo '{ "packageName": "nifi" }' > ~/tmp/swagger-nifi-python-    config.json && \
rm -rf ~/tmp/nifi-python-client && \
swagger-codegen generate \
    --lang python \
    --config swagger-nifi-python-config.json \
    --api-package apis \
    --model-package models \
    --template-dir /path/to/nipyapi/swagger_templates \
    --input-spec /path/to/nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-    bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-api/target/swagger-ui/swagger.json     \
    --output ~/tmp/nifi-python-client
```